# C++ errors - C4819, C2761, C2447

Tags: c++

I am using Visual Studio 2017 to learn about SFML and sprite animations but I cannot get this code to run.

I have it saved with the encoding "Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    // Create the main window
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML window");
    // Load a sprite to display
    sf::Texture texture;
    if (!texture.loadFromFile("professor_walk_cycle_no_hat.png"))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    sf::Sprite sprite(texture);

    // Start the game loop
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // Process events
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // Close window: exit
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        // Clear screen
        window.clear();
        // Draw the sprite
        window.draw(sprite);
        // Update the window
        window.display();
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am getting the following errors/warnings:

- Warning   C4819   The file contains a character that cannot be represented in the current code page (949). Save the file in Unicode format to prevent data loss   HelloSFML line: 1
- Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
  Error   C2761   '{ctor}': redeclaration of member is not allowed line: 3
- Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
  Error   C2447   '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) line: 4

Comment: `int main()` should be `int main(int argc, char **argv)`

Comment: Are you sure you're compiline it as C++ and not C? The last error looks like it thinks this is a C program.

Comment: @Barmar yes, it is C++

Comment: @Barmar Not necessarily, no. This example is perfectly legal.

Comment: @EricAhn what version of Windows are you using and which language?

Comment: @Marc.2377 Windows 10 and English (I changed the "Language for non-Unicode programs" to Korean (Korea)).

Comment: Line 3 is the blank line before `int main()`, I don't see how it can be complaining about a redefinition of `ctor` on that line.

Comment: @Marc.2377 The warning about "old-style formal list" suggests that it thinks this is C, which requires you to use `(void)` to indicate a function with no arguments, rather than C++.

Comment: @Barmar I see. Thanks.

Comment: Did you copy/paste some of this? If so you might want to check for unwanted (invisible) characters...

Comment: @BobMorane I did copy it from someone else's tutorial but I did not copy/paste, I wrote it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has no invisible non-unicode characters that we can see, but when your system locale is set to Korean, you'll indeed get [warning C4819](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173715.aspx).

In order to fix this, in addition to saving your source file as UTF-8, you must also specify the **`/utf-8`** option to the Visual C++ compiler. Here's how:

> 1. Open the project Property Pages dialog box.
> 2. Expand the Configuration Properties, C/C++, Command Line folder.
> 3. In Advanced Options, add the /utf-8 option, and specify your preferred
>    encoding.
> 4. Choose OK to save your changes.
>
> (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt708821.aspx)

---

With that out of the way... I could not reproduce errors C2761 and C2447. The code compiles and runs without issue. It is not a matter of C compilation (as opposed to C++) or else much more serious errors would arise. Let me know if it persists with `/utf-8`, so I can investigate some more.

Comment: sorry for the really late answer, i was tired of the error, i reinstalled VS 2017 and now it works, i dont even know why...

Comment: @EricAhn interesting. Thanks for letting me know. Regards.