# Convert utf8 wstring to string on windows in C++

Tags: c++, string

I am representing folder paths with boost::filesystem::path which is a wstring on windows OS and I would like to convert it to std::string with the following method:

```
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> conv1;
shared_dir = conv1.to_bytes(temp.wstring());
```

but unfortunatelly the result of the following text is this:

"c:\git\myproject\bin\árvíztűrőtükörfúrógép" ->
"c:\git\myproject\bin\Ã¡rvÃ­ztÅ±rÅ‘tÃ¼kÃ¶rfÃºrÃ³gÃ©p"

What do I do wrong?

```
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>

int main()
{
    // wide character data
    std::wstring wstr =  L"árvíztűrőtükörfúrógép";

    // wide to UTF-8
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> conv1;
    std::string str = conv1.to_bytes(wstr);
}
```

I was checking the value of the variable in visual studio debug mode.

Comment: Why would you store UTF-8 in a `std::wstring`?

Comment: Are you using C++17? If so, consider `std::filesystem` instead. `path` has a `generic_u8string()` method. that might be useful. Btw, how are you printing the converted string? Are you using `std::wcout`? You should probably not mix `std::cout` and `std::wcout` too much.

Comment: Not convinced by the duplicate. It may not consider the OP's specific encoding needs. Instead I'd like to see a [mcve] and a full explanation of the circumstances of the bug.

Comment: Also how do you witness this result? Are you sure you're not just misinterpreting `shared_dir` as ASCII?

Comment: @eerorika I suspect the title is just wrong/misleading though ofc we cannot be sure right now

Comment: "*but unfortunatelly the result of the following text is this*" - `Ã¡rvÃ­ztÅ±rÅ‘tÃ¼kÃ¶rfÃºrÃ³gÃ©p` is the UTF-8 encoded form of `árvíztűrőtükörfúrógép` being *misinterpreted* as ANSI instead of UTF-8. The code is fine, the data is correct, it is just the *display* of the UTF-8 data that is faulty.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Unfortunatelly I am only using C++14.I am using the VS locals to check the contain of the variables.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Minimal example is added to the post. Also, how could I misinterpret shared_dir as ASCII?

Comment: @Csuszmusz There are many such ways. Bad terminal settings, for example. There's still no minimal example because you do not show us how you are witnessing the behaviour. What do you _do_ with `shared_dir` at the end of this program? Where you look at it? In what? With what settings? Your example does not even output the string!

Comment: Part1 @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thank you for your answer and the solution ideas that you are implying with it. So basically I was checking the value of the variable in visual studio debug mode. I also tried to convert the variable back with conv1.from_bytes and I got back the right result.

Comment: Part2 @LightnessRacesinOrbit Also I tried this code snippet that I inserted above in a sandbox project and I see the "árvíztűrőtükörfúrógép" correctly, so the problem should be project specific. This lead me to the following question: [possible_root_cause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58013410/stdlocale-throws-runtime-error-exception-to-en-us-utf-8-locale)

Comment: Okay, then I have posted an answer on that basis.

Comment: Check out my answer to [C++ Visual Studio character encoding issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40337240/3258851) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49567787/3258851). Also, since you are using Boost, consider `boost::locale::conv::utf_to_utf<char>(wstr);`, since the `<codecvt>` header is deprecated in C++17.

Comment: @Marc.2377 I don't believe either of those answers are relevant.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Having now seen your answer, I agree, you're right. I think I'll leave the comment, though.

Answer (score 3):

The code is fine.

You're taking a `wstring` that stores UTF-16 encoded data, and creating a `string` that stores UTF-8 encoded data.

> I was checking the value of the variable in visual studio debug mode.

Visual Studio's debugger has no idea that your string stores UTF-8. A `string` just contains bytes. Only you (and people reading your documentation!) know that you put UTF-8 data inside it. You could have put something else inside it.

So, in the absence of anything more sensible to do, the debugger just renders the string as ASCII*. What you're seeing is the ASCII* representation of the bytes in your string.

**Nothing is wrong here.**

If you were to output the string like `std::cout << str`, and if you were running the program in a command line window set to UTF-8, you'd get your expected result. Furthermore, if you inspect the individual bytes in your string, you'll see that they are encoded correctly and hold your desired values.

You *can* push the IDE to decode the string as UTF-8, though, on an as-needed basis: in the Watch window type `str,s8`; or, in the Command window, type `? &str[0],s8`. These techniques are explored by Giovanni Dicanio in his article "[What's Wrong with My UTF-8 Strings in Visual Studio?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/gdicanio/2016/11/22/whats-wrong-with-my-utf-8-strings-in-visual-studio/)".

---

<sub>It's not even really ASCII; it'll be some 8-bit encoding decided by your system, most likely the code page [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) given the platform. ASCII only defines the lower 7 bits. Historically, the various 8-bit code pages have been colloquially (if incorrectly) called "extended ASCII" in various settings. But the point is that the multi-byte nature of the data is not at all considered by the component rendering the string to your screen, let alone specifically its UTF-8-ness.</sub>

Comment: ASCII doesn't have any accented letters. Please don't tell me this is "the extended ASCII" either, there's no such thing. This is most likely CP1252.

Comment: @n.m. Well, granted - I have added a caveat

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I really appreciate your answer and your time and I tried this method in VS Watch and you was correct, I saw the right format, but then I called the boost::filesystem::create_directories(str) both in my project and both in my sandbox project and the folder was created had different names. In my sandbox project it was the correct folder name with accents, but in my project the folder had this name: ĂˇrvĂ­ztĹ±rĹ‘tĂĽkĂ¶rfĂşrĂłgĂ©p. I suppose there is still an encoding issue, but I can not wrap my head around this.

Comment: @Csuszmusz Again you need to provide the encoding appropriate to the task. You are passing UTF-8 to `boost::filesystem::create_directories()` on Windows; this converts the arg to `boost::filesystem::path` (because that's what the function takes), and you already know that such a path should be a `wstring` holding UTF-16. You'll have to re-encode it back again! (There _is_ [a feature to do this autonomously](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-Encoding-conversions) but I think you have to play with locales to make it work the way you want)

Comment: Part1 @LightnessRacesinOrbit To extend why do I need this is that because I am using boost ipc and I am overriding the get_shared_dir(std::string &shared_dir); function which takes a string and if I create_directories with boost::path as a parameter the directory name is correct but the function gives back the string containing the ĂˇrvĂ­ztĹ±rĹ‘tĂĽkĂ¶rfĂşrĂłgĂ©p  and boost is using it inside the boost library where I can not explicit re-encode the string back and it is looking for the folder with utf8 name which will not exist, so it looks like the root cause is indeed the locales.

Comment: Part2 @LightnessRacesinOrbit ... which lead me to this problem: [locale setting issue] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58013410/stdlocale-throws-runtime-error-exception-to-en-us-utf-8-locale) Also thanks again for your time and support.

Comment: You keep linking to that page, and I don't know why because it does not seem to have anything to do with this question. This is not fundamentally about locales; it's about you providing the wrong input to library functions. It's simple: if a function expects a string with UTF-8 in it, provide that. If a function expects a wstring with UTF-16 in it, provide that. Convert between them as needed (but try to do so a little as possible because this takes time!)