# std::locale throws runtime_error exception to "en_US.UTF-8" locale

Tags: c++, localization, visual-studio-2019

So I have a strange issue with the following code snippet in my project with std::locale:

```
std::locale local;     
try {
    local = std::locale ("en_US.UTF-8");
}
catch (std::runtime_error &e) {
    std::cout  << e.what();
}
```

It throws an exception with a message: "bad locale name" in my production code, but in case I run it in an empty sandbox project it set the local correctly.

I suppose my project has a config somewhere that I am not familiar with, but I do not have any clue where should I look or where can it be set. In my project I tried it in the beginning of the main() function to eliminate the possibility that it is set somewhere else in the code, this why I am guessing it is set somewhere in a config file.

I am compiling in with configuration: Debug Win32

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should you not be using a hyphen rather than underscore? e.g. en-US vs en_US

Comment: A deployment problem would be the most obvious cause.  VS2019 still uses the runtime DLLs with the same name as the ones used in VS2015 and VS2017, msvcp140.dll is the one that matters for locale.  But if you didn't copy them and got an old version left behind by some kind of installer then you'll have trouble.  You do have to deploy the Release build of your program btw, that last comment is pretty confusing.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for your answer. So I looked around and I saw the following settings in project properties: Target Platform Version: 8.1, Platform Toolset: Visual Studio 2015 (v140), Character Set: Use Unicode Character Set.

Do you think they can be relevant?

Comment: It is not relevant to the specific version of msvcp140.dll, you run with the one that was installed last.  Which will be the VS2019 version on your machine.  But not necessarily on the production machine if you forgot to copy it.  You must deploy these DLLs, hard requirement.  If you are uncomfortable about getting it right then use the [redist installer](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/), available under the "Other tools and frameworks" section.

Answer (score 0):

Locale names on Windows are different from those on modern POSIX-ish systems. In particular, they never include "UTF-8" or anything similar.

There is no support for UTF-8 in Windows that can be turned on by selecting a standard locale. You may or may not have better luck with [Boost.Locale](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/locale/doc/html/index.html).