# Why can't we convert an integer found using xor operation to a character?

Tags: c++

When I write the code

```
    string s="000000";
    string d="111111";
    int x=(int)s[0]&(int)d[0];
    char y= (char)x;
    cout <<y << endl;
```

It works perfectly well and gives me the answer 0.

However, if I replace "&" by "^" (XOR) in the above code, the output given to me is just blank.

Why does this happen?

Note-

1. I tried to replace `(int)s[0]^(int)d[0]` by `((int)s[0]+(int)d[0])%2` but nothing changed in the result.
2. I tried to introduce another variable to see if that solves the problem. But again nothing changed.

   ```
   string s="000000";
   string d="111111";
   int x=(int)s[0]^(int)d[0];
   int z=x;
   char y= (char)z;
   cout <<y << endl;
   ```

Comment: put `char y = '0' + z` whicih would make y what you need

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Please feel free to put your answers in the answer section

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I voted to close this question, because I don't see why OP is performing random bit operations on chars and expect the results to be printable. The question is missing "expected output" to make it clear what is wrong. I suppose my comment is obsolete now with answers being present.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Just because you voted to close doesn't mean you should post answers in comments. Actually it suggests you didn't want to answer it _at all_, so...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's assume that your system uses ASCII character encoding (or extended ASCII or UTF-8).

In ASCII, the character '0' is represented by the value 48 (110000₂), and '1' is represented by 49 (110001₂)

110000₂ AND 110001₂ = 110000₂ which represents '0'.

110000₂ XOR 110001₂ = 000001₂ which is a non-printable character that represents start of a heading.

Comment: What is "extended ASCII"?

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Extended ASCII are 8-bit character encodings with the 0-127 having identical representation as the 7-bit US-ASCII such as ISO/IEC 8859 for example.

Comment: It was a rhetorical question - extended ASCII might be [a useful colloquial term](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58014687/560648) for the near-infinite 8-bit encodings but it's not "a real thing" so maybe we should just drop it here ;)

Comment: (I'm nitpicking, obviously - particularly as the facts of the OP's case do not change for any encoding that could be called "extended ASCII")

Answer (score 0):

> Why does this happen?

Because you are performing bitwise operations on the integral values that encode the characters. You need to:

1. Convert the characters `'0'` and `'1'` to the integers `0` and `1`.
2. Perform the bitwise operations on the integers.
3. Convert the resultant to a character.

```
char c1 = s[0];
char c2 = d[0];

int i1 = c1 - '0';
int i2 = c2 - '0';

int res_i = i1 ^ i2;

char res_c = res_i + '0';
```

That will work as long as `c1` and `c2` are limited to the characters `'0'` and `'1'`